# Companion object in scala

Tags: scala, try-catch, scala-3

I am trying to write an **toFirstOrSecond** method that will allow me to call Try without any extra code.

```
object A:
  enum FirstOrSecond[+V]:

    case First(x: V) extends FirstOrSecond[V]

    case Second(e : Throwable) extends FirstOrSecond[V]

    def map[Q](f: V ⇒ Q): FirstOrSecond[Q] =
      this match
        case FirstOrSecond.Second(e)  ⇒ FirstOrSecond.Second(e)
        case FirstOrSecond.First(v)   ⇒ Try { FirstOrSecond.First(f(v)) }.toFirstOrSecond match 
                    case FirstOrSecond.First(m)    => FirstOrSecond.First(f(v))
                    case FirstOrSecond.Second(m)   => FirstOrSecond.Second(m) 

  object Try:
    def toFirstOrSecond[Q](f: Try[Q]): FirstOrSecond[Q] =
      f match
        case Failure(e) => FirstOrSecond.First(e)
        case Success(v) => FirstOrSecond.Second(v)
```

But I get an error `object Try in object A does not take parameters` How do i solve this? Thanks

Comment: You are shadowing the `Try` class with your custom object.

Comment: Yes, you need either some kind of `apply` on your own `Try`-object, or you have to rename it to something else so that it doesn't collide with the standard `Try`.

Moreover, the `case Second(e : Throwable) extends FirstOrSecond[V]` feels as if it should be `FirstOrSecond[Nothing]`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, yep, I tried to write mine apply ```def apply[V](v: FirstOrSecond[V]): Try[V] = new Try[V]```, but then the method "toFirstOrSecond" generally completely lit up red when calling

Comment: Could you then please show what the `Try` is? There is currently only the `Try`-singleton `object`, but nothing that would provide a type constructor `Try[V]`. In general, please make sure to provide all the code that is required to reproduce the specific compiler error that you're struggling with.