# Add new method to type class in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-3

I'm trying to add new method `toA()` to utils.Try class.
But I am facing a problem of type:

case Success returns us `v : Any`, but I need `v : V`. How to get `v : V`?
Perhaps I need a function `Apply`? I'm new to this and I don't understand

```
object Example:

  enum AorB[+V]:

    case A(x: V) extends AorB[V]

    case B(x : Throwable) extends AorB[V]

  implicit class Try[V](x : V):

    def apply[V](r: => V): Try[V] = ???

    def toA[V](f: Try[V]): A[V] =
      f match
        case Success(v) =>  AorB.A(v) 
        case Failure(e) => AorB.B(e)
```

Comment: Where's definition of `Success`?

Comment: @Dima, Success/Failure are from scala.util.{Try,Success,Failure}

Comment: You `f` is of type `Example.Try`, not `scala.util.Try`. So, `case Success(v)` will never match.

Comment: You probably want to do [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/UtOwXMhpTVGvDqetjSCKQw/2) - I would recommend you to take a basic tutorial or read the docs since it seems you are just trying random things until it compiles.

Comment: I'd recommend a proper extension method if you're using Scala 3.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, thank you! I didn’t know about extension. Add your comment as answer, i will mark it correct

Comment: [Homework assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67066088/companion-object-in-scala)?

Comment: @jwvh same course i think